# Rewriting Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Currently I am working on a blog engine in RoR and I encounter severa issues with routing.
The `routes.rb` looks like this:

```
match '/admin', :to => 'posts#new'
match '/get/:id', :to => 'posts#get'
match '/new', :to => 'posts#new'
delete '/:id', :to => 'posts#destroy'
post '/edit/:id', :to => 'posts#update'
put '/edit/:id', :to => 'posts#update'
get '/edit/:id', :to => 'posts#new', :as => 'post'
get '/:slug', :to => 'posts#show', :as => 'post'
root :to => 'posts#index'
```

and I would like to transform it in something like:

```
resources :admin do
  resources :posts
end
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit more information is needed. What do you want to place in the admin resource? Only posting, or also editing?

But a few tips to get started:
- You have to split your posts-controller. Make a subfolder in the controllers called admin (the resource name). Move the admin-functions to this controller, and leave the public posts-function (index and show) in the normal posts_controller.
- Do the same for the views.

And, i suspect you want the routes to be:

```
namespace :admin
  resources :posts
end

get '/:id', :to => 'posts#show'

root :to => 'posts#index'
```

Then you can put some form of authentication to the admin namespace.

Hope this helps you on the way.